# Image scaling on canvas with fabric js

Tags: image, canvas, svg, scaling

[Please check attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNqJW.png) 
I have set image using setFill to svg image. Once image get set I have to change width, height or perform operation on image. How I can get fill image object when user select svg on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

scaling :

```
        image.on('scaling', function (opt) {

        var r = canvas.getRetinaScaling();
        var sX = Math.abs(this.scaleX) * r;
        var sY = Math.abs(this.scaleY) * r;

        canvas.setWidth(image.width * sX);
        canvas.setHeight(image.height * sY);

        canvas.renderAll();
   });



   $("#save1").click(function () {



var arrFormat = g_filename.split('.');
var arrFilename = g_filename.split('/');
var filename;
var format;

if (arrFormat.length == 1)
    format = "image/" + "jpg";
else {
    format = "image/" + arrFormat[arrFormat.length - 1];
}

if (arrFilename == 1)
    filename = g_filename;
else {
    filename = arrFilename[arrFilename.length - 1];
}


var serverUrl = "/Home/UploadImg5";
var imageName = filename;

// 이미지를 첫번째것을 가져온다.
var obj = canvas.item(0);


var width = Math.abs(image.width * image.scaleX);
var height = Math.abs(image.height * image.scaleY);



var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: format, left: obj.left, top: obj.top, width: width / ratio, height: height / ratio });

canvas.discardActiveObject();
canvas.renderAll();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: serverUrl,
    data: {
        title: imageName,
        type: "jpg",
        image: dataURL // Step 1에서 가져온 데이터
    }
}).done(function () {

    console.log('saved!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `Fabric.js` URL for better understanding. see: [link](http://fabricjs.com/dynamic-patterns)